# PostgreSQL - Grant select on all tables (and future tables), in *all schemas*

Tags: sql, postgresql, schema

My database uses schemas to separate tenant-specific data for an application - each customer has a brand new schema created when they sign up to hold their data.

This obviously means I don't know the name of all schemas ahead of time.

I'd like to create a `readonly` role that has read access to *all* of these schemas, and those created in the future.

All questions along these lines I've found require knowing the name of the schemas, e.g.:

```
-- Create a group
CREATE ROLE readaccess;

-- Grant access to existing tables
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA a_given_schema TO readaccess;
GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA a_given_schema TO readaccess;

-- Grant access to future tables
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA a_given_schema GRANT SELECT ON TABLES TO readaccess;

-- Create user with password
CREATE USER readonly WITH PASSWORD 'a_secret';
GRANT readaccess TO readonly;
```

Is there a way to do something like this, but for all schemas in the future?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't make that, as said here : [grant usage & privileges on future created schema in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31635662/grant-usage-privileges-on-future-created-schema-in-postgresql)

The best is to think the other way: every time you create a schema, you GRANT the role at the same time: (Take a look at the link for more information)

> ```
> CREATE FUNCTION new_user_schema (user text, pwd text) RETURNS void AS $$
> DECLARE
>   usr name;
>   sch name;
> BEGIN
>   -- Create the user
>   usr := quote_identifier(user);
>   EXECUTE format('CREATE ROLE %I LOGIN PASSWORD %L', usr, quote_literal(pwd));
>
>   -- Create the schema named after the user and set default privileges
>   sch := quote_identifier('sch_' || user);
>   EXECUTE format('CREATE SCHEMA %I', sch);
>   EXECUTE format('ALTER SCHEMA %I OWNER TO %L', sch, usr);
>   EXECUTE format('ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA %I
>                     GRANT SELECT ON TABLES TO %L', sch, usr);
> END; $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql STRICT;
> ```